# How to use Firestore right

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to know what is better:

The example is a shopping app and it is about the Main screen with a List of every Item available.

A) One document, for example "productList", with a Map in it where every Category, following another Map with every productId and a List with Data like the product Title, the showcase Image and the price.
Example code:

```
Stream stream = db.collection('products').document('productList').snapshots().asyncMap((list) => list.data);
```

or

B) many documents in a collection called "products" where the data is stored.
Example code:

```
Stream stream = db.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: "CategoryName").snapshots().map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => doc.data));
```

(Both are working but with B i got with 3 products muuuuch more document reads wherefore i thought A would save a lot product reads but opening the question if there could be problems with that method)

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go with the first approach of trying to put everything into a single document, you will have scalability problems when the number of products becomes large.  A Firestore document can only contain 1MB of data.  After that, writes to it will fail, and you will have a hard time restructuring your app and its data in order to resolve the issue.

The only "right" way to store lots of items is to use one document for each item.  The exception to this is when you have a hard guarantee about the number of items, and you are absolutely certain that the data for all those items can always fit into one document.